How to create sheet in Tableau which would count all of the dates based on how they are flagged? On Time/Late and Same Date/Later Date
Hello!                                                                                                           In Tableau I've created such table, in which I've got all of the Number Orders  and the Comitted, Requested and Actual Delivery Dates. The dates are compared to each other and give us statuses. The problem I've got is to count all of the statuses in the other sheet.
Sales Order Numbers is in STRING data type
Comitted, Requested and Actual Delivery Dates are in DATE data type
Requested vs Comitted is in STRING data type
Comitted vs Actual is in STRING data type
Number of Sales Orders is in INT data type
First I wanted to get rid of all the NULL statuses, which I don't have the dates for yet. I only care about the orders which are already delivered. But I couldn't filter these out as when I tried to drag in this case Committed vs Requested to Filter Shelf nothing happened, so this is the first issue.     Second one is that I wanted to change the data from the Bar Chart to table but this option is turned off, I don't know why.

Could you please give me some advice how differently I could put together those tables in Tableau so I get similar result as it is on the photo below? I want all of statuses so in this example "Later date" and "On time" be counted

